# Почему пушится только последний элемент да и еще вместо всех остальных?

Tags: javascript, массивы

```
for (var i=0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
    row['Option names'] = data[0][i];
    row['Option values'] = data[1][i];
    console.log(row);
    rows.push(row);
}
```

Почему в консоли отображаются все row-ы как надо, а в массиве rows вместо, допустим, 10 разных row-ов, я получаю 10 одинаковых row-ов, а именно все они как  последний row ???

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно `row` - это у вас объект, а объект, как известно, передается по ссылке. Выход: объявлять `row` внутри цикла и использовать его там.

```
for (var i=0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
    let row = {};
    row['Option names'] = data[0][i];
    row['Option values'] = data[1][i];
    console.log(row);
    rows.push(row);
}
```

Comment: @РустамГимранов можно. Но я без понятия что ТС там делает еще внутри, а гадать  я не собираюсь

Comment: @РустамГимранов если включить логику, то можно увидеть название `row` и цикл, а значит подразумевается множественное число элементов с одинаковым набором, который каждый раз в цикле будет новый и заполняться в переменную, а значит бессмысленны действия с первым элементом. Тем не менее, если там что-то и происходит, то более чем очевидно - это можно вписать уже в рамки полученных знаний о том, почему сейчас происходит так, как происходит. А